# I want to change color of radio button dot in red when it is selected

Tags: flutter

```
Radio<String>(
                      activeColor: WHITE,
                      value: "video",
                      groupValue: _radioBtnVal,
                      onChanged: _handleChange),
 Text(
                    "Video Call",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: _radioBtnVal == 'video' ? WHITE : BLACK,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio/activeColor.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you, refer documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html)

> Declare one enum

```
 enum SingingCharacter { clickradio}
```

> Your Widget

```
  ListTile(
      title: const Text('Click Radio'),
      leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
        activeColor: Colors.red,
        value: SingingCharacter.clickradio,
        groupValue: _character,
        onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
          setState(() {
            _character = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
```

Your Output Screen -> [image]

Comment: I want to change dot's color......I don't want to change outer circle's color